# Configure programmatic deployment for Azure Bing maps

Tags: azure, bing-maps, azure-resource-manager

I'm trying to add `BingMaps` to our resource template.

this is the template so far:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "mapsName": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-07-02",
      "type": "Microsoft.BingMaps/mapApis",
      "name": "[parameters('mapsName')]",
      "location": "westus",
      "plan": {
        "publisher": "bingmaps",
        "product": "mapapis",
        "name": "myMapsTest",
        "promotionCode": null
      },
      "properties": {
        "provisioningState": "Succeeded"
      }
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {
  }
}
```

It gives this error message:

> New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 14:22:50 - Resource
>   Microsoft.BingMaps/mapApis 'myMapsName' failed with message 'User
>   failed validation to purchase resources. Error message: 'Legal terms
>   have not been accepted for this item on this subscription. To accept
>   legal terms, please go to the Azure portal
>   (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=534873) and configure
>   programmatic deployment for the Marketplace item or create it there
>   for the first time''

How can I configure programmatic deployment for Azure Bing maps?

Answer (score 1):

The current workaround is: **create the marketplace item once under the very same subscription you are going to use for the programmatic deployment. It worked me like charm.**. (although I am not happy this interactive hocus pocus at all)

The supposed correct solution is not working yet (issue), but hopefully will. See below:

[image]

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/working-with-marketplace-images-on-azure-resource-manager/ seem to be the only way

Comment: As of today, this is still not implemented. Though my investigation confirms this is how it is SUPPOSED to work. Lame. Note that this also applies if you are trying to provision a SendGrid account, as is the case for me.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be an Azure Subscription issue - what type of subscription do you have (pay as you go, free, EA?). 
What location did you try to deploy to?
Also - are you able to provision "Bing Maps API for Enterprise" offering for the marketplace?

Comment: I tried on free MSDN subscription and pay as you go too. I was able to provision such a resource from azure portal (once I accept the terms).

Comment: What region have you tried to use while using the template? (location)

Comment: This provider is only available in West US location

Comment: You should enable programmatic access in your subscription. Follow the instruction in this [post](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/working-with-marketplace-images-on-azure-resource-manager/). Look for "enable the SKU for programmatic access"

Comment: Just tried that and there's no option to configure programmatic deployment for Bing Maps in particular.

Comment: Can you try to do that for another Marketplace offering, such as Wowza?(that is mentioned in the blog post). It should enable programmatic configuration in general in your subscription.

Comment: Yes, I was able to do it for the resource in the example you provided, however this is not available (for me) for Bing maps.

Comment: try now running your template for bing

Comment: Hi Nava, thank you for your efforts. I did that and I still get the error message. I do not have the option to configure Bing Maps API for programatic deployment. See image: http://postimg.org/image/63zc3j981/